# MySQL Data Removal without delete cascade

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a project where I'm simulating a social network on MySQL. 
This is my first year and first time working with SQL. 
To simplify I have table User that can have multiple Videos, which have a foreign key to the user.

There are also Comments on the Videos by Users and ratings on the Videos by Users, all these also having foreign keys, I think you get the idea.

On the project pdf the teacher asks to remove data through `StoredProcedures` without using the option `DELETE CASCADE`.

They say to remove the data assuring the referential integrity.
Any ideas of what this could be?
Because I have to remove or 'make invisible I guess' all data that contains the `user_id` that I give by parameter. Please help if you can :)

Any sugestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the tables that are linked together using the user_id, just write a DELETE query for each of them that you then trigger when you delete a user.  Be sure and put semi-colons at the end of each query so it knows where one ends and the next begins.

```
DELETE FROM video_table WHERE user_id=declared_user_id_param;
DELETE FROM comments_table WHERE user_id=declared_user_id_param;
```

Comment: You must just be carefull in the order you delete the data, from child to parent